# Sql Server union with If condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query like:

```
DECLARE @tmpValue
SET @tmpValue = 0 -- it will be change 

SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE AniActive = 1
UNION 
IF @tmpValue > 0 
SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE.Active = 0
```

When I use like this it is giving error because of if condition. I have to use UNION because of our structure.

How can I use it with if condition?

Thanks, 
John

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Move the condition `@tmpValue > 0` to the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE AniActive = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE @tmpValue > 0 AND Active = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to put condition in Query is CASE statement . you can put any number of condition 
in query . CASE statement is used to put conditional filters in Query .

For EX.

```
DECLARE @tmpValue
SET @tmpValue = 0 -- it will be change 

SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE AniActive = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Animal 
WHERE 
1 = CASE WHEN @tmpValue  = 0 THEN 0 ELSE Active = 1 END
```

your situation is not to complex but for more complex condition you can use nested CASE statement in Query .

Answer (score 3):

You can add your condition to the query like this. the section part of the union will simply return no results if your test condition is false:

```
DECLARE @tmpValue

SET @tmpValue = 0 -- it will be change 

SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE AniActive = 1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE.Active = 0 and @tmpValue > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to do it that simplifies the code by getting rid of the UNION altogether. I always prefer a simpler solution where possible. This will also perform better if the select does a table scan, since it will only scan it once rather than (potentially) twice.

```
DECLARE @tmpValue

SET @tmpValue = 0 -- it will be change

SELECT * FROM Animal WHERE AniActive = 1 OR @tmpValue > 0
```