# Skip Union Statement when condition is not true within SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am needing to automate a report to go out on a monthly basis that uses End of Month tables. Currently, I have to go in every month and adding in the new monthly table within the subquery in order for the data to be accurate. Is there a way to union an additional query if a condition is TRUE. The condition in question is the date. The 01/2021 table doesn't exist until 02/01/2021, so I don't want to read in the two lines until then because SQL fails when it reads in a non existing table. Code Below:

```
Select * FROM

(Select '12.2020' as [Starting Point], [CustomerID],[Days]
from dbo.EOM_Table_202012

UNION ALL
---Insert IF statement and jump over lines if date is not greater than 01/31/2021
Select '1.2021' as [Starting Point],[CustomerID],[Days]
from dbo.EOM_Table_202101) a
```

Comment: There is a similar answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176954/sql-server-union-with-if-condition).

Comment: The true underlying problem here is that you use relational tables as if they were spreadsheets, which they aren't. Don't have a separate table for every month. Have *exactly one*  table for all data and include a column that denotes the month (or day or timestamp) in that table. If you need data monthwise (or for any other period, you're completely flexible here) you can do that in a `WHERE` clause when querying the table.

Comment: While that is a decent idea, I don't control the tables. I am stuck with EOM tables for every month and need to union all of them together with a month.year column, ID column, and one more additional column.

Comment: Is there a way? Yes - using dynamic sql to query the metadata of the database to determine which tables exist and can be referenced.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a view to help "automate" this. The view contains your union statement. You would need to add to your current process that creates the newest month-end table to also alter the view to keep it in sync with the new table.

Comment: I don't have permissions to edit table structures, create new tables or views. I could create temp tables within my query, but don't know how to set that up along with my problem above.

Comment: How many tables do you plan to UNION? Don't know about SQLServer, but Access has a limit of 50 SELECT.